# After changing resolution, pixelated screen

Tags: fedora, display

I am using Fedora 23 GNOME with a Dell Precision m3800 with a default `3200x1800` resolution. All system tools (like terminal, nautilus) are displayed in a pleasant way. Even Google Chrome, or some few other installed software are looking good. But most of the installed application are not optimized for this resolution or rather that small, that almost no one can read it (at least me not). I thought, well, just change the resolution to `1920x1080`, what I did. No almost every application has a pleasant size, **but** fonts, images, everything looks just not in HD anymore. Images or fonts looking pixelated etc.

Any idea how I can get this fixed? Do I have maybe to install a graphic driver (even if this is not recommended)?

Comment: Do you have 1600×900 as an option, instead of 1920×1080? How does that look?

Comment: @mattdm Not good either. Don't know what to do.